# read command not parsing double quotes

Tags: bash

When I use this function:

```
    function get_firefox_default_profile_path {
    local firefox_profiles_path="/Users/whatever/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles"

    local IFS=$'\n'
    local profiles_found
    read -r -d '' profiles_found <<EOF
    $(/usr/bin/find "$firefox_profiles_path" \
    -type d \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -regex "$FIREFOX_DEFAULT_PROFILE_REGEX")
EOF
    echo "${profiles_found[0]#.*}"
}
```

I do get the following result:

```
find: /Users/whatever/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles: No such file or directory
```

Yes, the folder itself exists...why is not read taking into account the double quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the backslash from the `firefox_profiles_path` variable.

Comment: I don't see in your code that any double quotes would be passed to `read`, except if you have files (which are produced by  your `find`) which have double quotes in their name. Perhaps you can transform your case into a minimal reproducible problem, which we can execute?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `read` instead of just `profiles_found=$(/usr/bin/find ...etc...)`? Also, in either case, `profiles_found` is just a plain variable, not an array, so `profiles_found[0]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson, it was the backslash...looking for something complicated when in the end I was the problem XD

Answer (score 0):

Removing the backslash from the 1st variable fixed the issue.